# How to compile MethodCallExpression without DynamicInvoke?

Tags: c#, ios, lambda, xamarin

I have a `MethodCallExpression` that contains date calls like this

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10);
```

I'd like to be able to compile that into the actual date that it represents, but because I'm using Xamarin, and building for iOS, I can't use the DynamicInvoke() method due to AOT Compilation limitations.

```
var expression = MyExpression;
if (expression.Type.Name == "DateTime")
{
    // Can't do this. Even though it works in most cases
    string result = Expression.Lambda( expression ).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I can tell after some research... there's no way to do the compilation from within the ExpressionVisitor, simply because it would need to be Just-In-Time compiled, which isn't allowed on iOS.

The alternative for us is to accept this as a limitation, and change our query.

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10);
var actualExpression = TestExpression<UserModel>( u => u.CreatedDate == date );
```

Now we're pre-compiling the code before passing it into the Expression Tree.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - due to the [limitations](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/) of dynamic code generation on iOS, you cannot perform a compilation. Your only option is some sort of interpreter (perhaps [PaxScript](http://eco148-88394.innterhost.net/paxscriptnet/)?)

Update: The paxScript page says the code is compatible with Mono for Android. Try the version that is compatible with WinRT and WP7/8. Those platforms have similar restrictions to iOS.

Comment: sorry, additional libraries add unwanted / unneeded bloat. If there's a library that can do it, then it can be done without the lib. I'm just digging into how.

Comment: Writing an interpreter is a project unto itself. However, you could probably tailor yours to only cater to methods that you might encounter (which might simplify things).

Comment: Ok, I'm visiting this PaxScripter to just get this going until I have time to roll my own. The example is a little convoluted on how to run the `scripter.Invoke()`

Comment: The method that I need to be able to call... `public static Data.ExpressionVisitor TestExpression<TModel> (Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression ) where TModel : class, new()`

Comment: It appears as though an Interpreter like PaxScript is doing the same (or similar) thing as compile. Therefore I don't think it runs on iOS either... though I haven't tested.